# Printng row in Python

Tags: python, cursor, arcpy

I have used cursors to create a new attribute table with python and arcpy however when I try to print the rows from the attribute data such as the country, city, & population only one city will be printed.

```
arcpy.CopyRows_management (folder_path + '\NA_Cities.shp', folder_path + '\Select_Cities.dbf')
fc = folder_path + '\Select_Cities.dbf'

The_cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['CNTRY_NAME', 'Population'])
for row in The_cursor:
    if row[0] == 'United States' and row[1] < 8000000:
        The_cursor.deleteRow()
    elif row [0] == 'Mexico' and row[1] < 8000000:
        The_cursor.deleteRow()
    elif row[0] == 'Canda' and row[1] < 3000000:
        The_cursor.deleteRow()
print row
```

Here is my result

```
Selecting locations

Please Stand By...

Removing the data that does not meet the requirements

[u'Canada', 25000.0]

Finished identifying the cities
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: you are in a for loop. as soon as one of the condition succeeds loop will move on to the next element in the list, in this case your query result. whatever it's returning.

Comment: Canda ... in your last elif ... we prefer Canada

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest **code necessary to reproduce it**. You don't show where your `print` statement is and so we can't tell you how to fix it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My apologies and thanks for the catching the typo.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply was out of town. I see so it's printing the last elif, and I will add print sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print *each* row in the loop, the `print row` statement needs to be within the loop.

```
for row in The_cursor:
    print row
    if row[0] == 'United States' and row[1] < 8000000:
        The_cursor.deleteRow()
    elif row [0] == 'Mexico' and row[1] < 8000000:
        The_cursor.deleteRow()
    elif row[0] == 'Canada' and row[1] < 3000000:
        The_cursor.deleteRow()
```

If you want only deleted rows to be printed, put that `print` statement within the `if`/`elif` conditionals.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
I was trying print everywhere except above the for statement